# Laravel Mail Notification - modify from address

Tags: laravel

I created a Notification with a mail notifiable. My problem is that I cant figure out how to set the from address.

Here's my toMail:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->from($this->email, $this->name)
        ->subject('Contact Form')
        ->line('Name: '.$this->name)
        ->line('Email: '.$this->email)
        ->line('Message: '.$this->message);
}
```

The from method does not work, and instead it uses the default mail config. Any ideas on why this is not working?

Comment: Small suggestion: when you're having trouble, try reading the docs! :-) You might find your answer much faster than writing up a question on SO. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#writing-mailables

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `from` method within your mailable class' `build` method:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('example@example.com')
                ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
}
```

You can also have a global `from` email. You do that in the `config/mail.php` configuration file:

```
'from' => ['address' => 'example@example.com', 'name' => 'App Name']
```

this will be used if no `from` address is specified in the mailable class' `build` method

[Here's a reference to the laravel documentation that explains the mail function in detail.](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail)